# Create a map showing routes less than 20 miles

Tags: maps

funny how your girlfriend stimulates an idea isn't it.
So we've been househunting for sometime, and the main constraint is commute time, however hard i look though there appears to be no way to create a map that shows estimated commute times from a set start point.

This seems odd to me as surely a tool that allowed this sort of data to be plotted would be of benefit to a number of users, supermarkets could show which was your nearest supermarket by driving distance rather than as the crow flies (something that has frustrated me previously)

So - where would i even start on a task like this? Google Maps seems like a good place to start, but apparently needs an A & B and won't function from an A & a distance. 
Somebody has suggested openmaps, but i'm not sure if the traffic is overlaid on there, which would definitely need to be a factor for my specific use case when we're talking about commutes.

I'm interested to hear different peoples takes on this, or even if a solution already exists out there (probably as a bespoke piece of software)

Thanks

Neil

Comment: I think the reason why nobody has done this or responded is that it's a difficult problem.

Comment: I think what you'd want is to drop, instead of a circle with a distance radius, a funky-shaped figure showing constant travel time.  To calculate that figure, you'd need to calculate the times for a bunch of candidate points and refine where the boundary between them was.   That's a lot of calls to the direction-finding API, and Google will only let you request 2500 per day.

Comment: You could get around Google's limits by using Open Street Map for your calculations, but OSM doesn't have traffic information.